# Different ways of saying "single"?

Tags: nuances, numbers

I am trying to translate basic combat to Japanese, but find myself struggling as to which form of "x of this" to use.
I am currently trying to figure out how to say "single," as in "single punch," with the following ones:

> 単(たん）-OR-
>   一重(ひとえ）-OR- 単一(たんいつ）

What is the rule of choosing between the (kunyomi number) + 重 and other forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you specifically mean a single punch you can say パンチ1発 or 1発のパンチ or alternatively ワンパン. There's a manga series called ワンパンマン, which plays on this idea to have a one punch KO. If you want to talk about say 2 punches you could say パンチ2発 or 2発のパンチ.